# background color is not appear in this context

Tags: html, css

This is a screenshot

[image]

This is a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b0cp6hmw/4/

This is my css

```
.slNewClass {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#e5412d;

    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
}
```

this is my html:

```
<div id="campaignDivTotalServiceLevel" runat="server">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a id="DropdownTotalServiceLevel" href="#" class="addWK">Add</a>
        <div class="slNewClass">
            <div class="details">

                <span class="content">Total Service Level</span>
                <span class="value" id="slSpan" runat="server">0%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

#### My need

I want to but the `Add` link exactly above the `red` div

#### What have I tried

I made my html is:

```
<div class="slCorrection">
        <div id="campaignDivTotalServiceLevel" runat="server">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a id="DropdownTotalServiceLevel" href="#" class="addWK">Add</a>
        <div class="slNewClass">
            <div class="details">

                <span class="content">Total Service Level</span>
                <span class="value" id="slSpan" runat="server">0%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in other words, I added a new div that will contains both the link and the red div.

then I changed my css to:

```
.slCorrection {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
.slNewClass {

    background-color:#e5412d;

    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
}
```

This is a jsfiddle that shows my tried

http://jsfiddle.net/b0cp6hmw/3/

#### The problem:

the background color is not shown

Comment: "My Need" and "The Problem" look like two separate things.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Dan I tried to shown you my need, what I tried, then my problem. I am trying to make the add link exactly above the red div, I succeed but i have another problem witch is the background is not shown

Comment: I added another solution based on the problem you have listed above. Hope it's working for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself

I just make

display:inline-block;

to `slnewclass`

and it works

Answer (score 1):

The background is not visible, because `.slNewClass` is `float`ed to the left. Basically, the `div` with the red background doesn't have anything static inside so the background size would by 0x0. You don't need the floting here (in version 3 of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b0cp6hmw/3/), you can just remove it.

Final version: http://jsfiddle.net/b0cp6hmw/6/

Comment: I ttied your solution and removed the float, but still the same proboem, no background

Comment: after your update, it is working on jsfiddle but not on my case, because i have more many elements, +1 I will try it on my machine better and update you

Answer (score 1):

you must set

```
 .addWK {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20%;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:5px;

}
.slNewClass {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    width:20%;
    height:20%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#e5412d;

    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
}
```

try the responsive version jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/b0cp6hmw/20/)

Comment: that makes both the link and the red div at the top, but I want them at the botton

Comment: what changes have you made please? have you deleted the correction class?

Comment: i see what you did, you changed the addwk class, but that class is used by more than 200 elemnts in the pages, i can't change it, could you make your new changes to a new class and assign the new class to the slnewclass css ?

Comment: I can't use your solution because you have assign 150 px with is static, but i don't know the hight of the `slnewclass` so your solution won't work osrry

Answer (score 1):

you can delete this code :
    .slNewClass
and add all its codes under the code :
.`slNewClass .details`
like this : http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadyousef/b0cp6hmw/17/

Answer (score 0):

you are having trouble because of this class, try it without this class, you will get it..
This is the faulted class

```
.slNewClass .details {
position: relative;
margin-left:15px;
z-index: 11;
float: left;
margin-top: 15px;
text-align: left;
}
```

good luck

you are having `float`, `zindex` may be those are the problem, get rid of them..

concentrate there...

Comment: i viewed your fiddle thats why i'm saying

Answer (score 0):

What about if you just use your solution in the second jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b0cp6hmw/3/

and you just add **`overflow:auto;`** to the .slNewClass class.

```
.slNewClass {    
    background-color:#e5412d;    
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:4px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

you will notice the background will appear and the 'Add' link will be on top.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/b0cp6hmw/22/